# Spring boot - Error creating bean with name Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a project in Spring boot, Java 17, maven with a connection SQL Server and I am running with IDE Intellij 2023.

This project was changed from Java 1.8 to Java 17, I changed all dependencies and versions, and I fixed some problems, but now I am receiving two kinds of errors:

First - If I don't use annotation `@Autowired` in my class `Service`:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '/sc/documentosNaoProtocolados': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarServices': Error creating bean with name 'viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarServices': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository': Error creating bean with name 'viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository' defined in br.coopercarga.com.br.repository.Logistica.ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class br.coopercarga.com.br.domain.Logistica.ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:716) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:696) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarServices': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository': Error creating bean with name 'viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository' defined in br.coopercarga.com.br.repository.Logistica.ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class br.coopercarga.com.br.domain.Logistica.ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:716) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:696) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
```

```
    @Service
    public class ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarServices {
    
        ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository;
    
        public Collection<ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar> load(FiltroDocumentosNaoProtocolados filtroDocumentosNaoProtocolados){
            return viwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository.load(filtroDocumentosNaoProtocolados.getCodigoSistemaUsuariosFiliais(),
                    filtroDocumentosNaoProtocolados.getDataInicial(),
                    filtroDocumentosNaoProtocolados.getDataFinal(),
                    filtroDocumentosNaoProtocolados.getContratoFreteNumero());
        }
    }
```

The second kind error, occurs when I use an annotation `@Autowired`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logisticaGLGLDocumentosRepository' defined in br.coopercarga.com.br.repository.Logistica.LogisticaGLGLDocumentosRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class br.coopercarga.com.br.domain.Logistica.TblLogisticaGlgldocumentos   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.coopercarga.com.br.domain.Logistica.TblLogisticaGlgldocumentos  at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]  at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]  at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:80) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]     at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
```

My repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisarRepository extends JpaRepository<ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar, Long> {
        @Query(nativeQuery = true,
                value = "SELECT *\n " +
                        "FROM viwLogistica_DocumentosNaoProtocolados_Pesquisar AS VIW\n " +
                        "WHERE VIW.PessoaCodigo IN (:listaCodigoGNPessoas) AND\n " +
                        "VIW.ContratoFreteDataEmissao >= :DataInicial AND VIW.ContratoFreteDataEmissao <= :DataFinal AND\n " +
                        "VIW.ContratoFreteNumero = CASE WHEN :ContratoFreteNumero IS NOT NULL AND :ContratoFreteNumero <> '' THEN :ContratoFreteNumero ELSE VIW.ContratoFreteNumero END\n" +
                        "ORDER BY NDias, ContratoFreteDataEmissao")
        Collection<ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar> load(@Param("listaCodigoGNPessoas") List<Long> listaCodigoGNPessoas,
                                                                        @Param("DataInicial") String dataInicial,
                                                                        @Param("DataFinal") String dataFinal,
                                                                        @Param("ContratoFreteNumero") String contratoFreteNumero);
    
    }
```

My entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "viwlogisticaDocumentosnaoprotocoladosPesquisar"
            , schema = "dbo"
    
    )
    public class ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar {
        private Long pessoaCodigo;
        private String pessoaNome;
        private String pessoaCPFCNPJ;
        private Long contratoFreteCodigo;
        private String contratoFreteNumero;
        private Date contratoFreteDataEmissao;
        private Long documentoCodigo;
        private String documentoNumero;
        private String documentoCliente;
        private String documentoSerie;
        private String cavaloPlaca;
        private String carretaPlaca;
        private String motorista;
        private String origem;
        private String destino;
        private String filial;
        private String nDias;
    
        public ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar() {
        }
    
        public ViwLogisticaDocumentosNaoProtocoladosPesquisar(Long pessoaCodigo, String pessoaNome, String pessoaCPFCNPJ, Long contratoFreteCodigo, String contratoFreteNumero, Date contratoFreteDataEmissao, Long documentoCodigo, String documentoNumero, String documentoCliente, String documentoSerie, String cavaloPlaca, String carretaPlaca, String motorista, String origem, String destino, String filial, String nDias) {
            this.pessoaCodigo = pessoaCodigo;
            this.pessoaNome = pessoaNome;
            this.pessoaCPFCNPJ = pessoaCPFCNPJ;
            this.contratoFreteCodigo = contratoFreteCodigo;
            this.contratoFreteNumero = contratoFreteNumero;
            this.contratoFreteDataEmissao = contratoFreteDataEmissao;
            this.documentoCodigo = documentoCodigo;
            this.documentoNumero = documentoNumero;
            this.documentoCliente = documentoCliente;
            this.documentoSerie = documentoSerie;
            this.cavaloPlaca = cavaloPlaca;
            this.carretaPlaca = carretaPlaca;
            this.motorista = motorista;
            this.origem = origem;
            this.destino = destino;
            this.filial = filial;
            this.nDias = nDias;
        }
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "Documentocodigo", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Long getDocumentoCodigo() {
            return documentoCodigo;
        }
    
        public void setDocumentoCodigo(Long documentoCodigo) {
            this.documentoCodigo = documentoCodigo;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Pessoacodigo")
        public Long getPessoaCodigo() {
            return pessoaCodigo;
        }
    
        public void setPessoaCodigo(Long pessoaCodigo) {
            this.pessoaCodigo = pessoaCodigo;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Pessoanome")
        public String getPessoaNome() {
            return pessoaNome;
        }
    
        public void setPessoaNome(String pessoaNome) {
            this.pessoaNome = pessoaNome;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Pessoacpfcnpj")
        public String getPessoaCPFCNPJ() {
            return pessoaCPFCNPJ;
        }
    
        public void setPessoaCPFCNPJ(String pessoaCPFCNPJ) {
            this.pessoaCPFCNPJ = pessoaCPFCNPJ;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Contratofretecodigo")
        public Long getContratoFreteCodigo() {
            return contratoFreteCodigo;
        }
    
        public void setContratoFreteCodigo(Long contratoFreteCodigo) {
            this.contratoFreteCodigo = contratoFreteCodigo;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Contratofretenumero")
        public String getContratoFreteNumero() {
            return contratoFreteNumero;
        }
    
        public void setContratoFreteNumero(String contratoFreteNumero) {
            this.contratoFreteNumero = contratoFreteNumero;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Contratofretedataemissao")
        public Date getContratoFreteDataEmissao() {
            return contratoFreteDataEmissao;
        }
    
        public void setContratoFreteDataEmissao(Date contratoFreteDataEmissao) {
            this.contratoFreteDataEmissao = contratoFreteDataEmissao;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Documentonumero")
        public String getDocumentoNumero() {
            return documentoNumero;
        }
    
        public void setDocumentoNumero(String documentoNumero) {
            this.documentoNumero = documentoNumero;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Documentocliente")
        public String getDocumentoCliente() {
            return documentoCliente;
        }
    
        public void setDocumentoCliente(String documentoCliente) {
            this.documentoCliente = documentoCliente;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Documentoserie")
        public String getDocumentoSerie() {
            return documentoSerie;
        }
    
        public void setDocumentoSerie(String documentoSerie) {
            this.documentoSerie = documentoSerie;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Cavaloplaca")
        public String getCavaloPlaca() {
            return cavaloPlaca;
        }
    
        public void setCavaloPlaca(String cavaloPlaca) {
            this.cavaloPlaca = cavaloPlaca;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Carretaplaca")
        public String getCarretaPlaca() {
            return carretaPlaca;
        }
    
        public void setCarretaPlaca(String carretaPlaca) {
            this.carretaPlaca = carretaPlaca;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Motorista")
        public String getMotorista() {
            return motorista;
        }
    
        public void setMotorista(String motorista) {
            this.motorista = motorista;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Origem")
        public String getOrigem() {
            return origem;
        }
    
        public void setOrigem(String origem) {
            this.origem = origem;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Destino")
        public String getDestino() {
            return destino;
        }
    
        public void setDestino(String destino) {
            this.destino = destino;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Filial")
        public String getFilial() {
            return filial;
        }
    
        public void setFilial(String filial) {
            this.filial = filial;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "Ndias")
        public String getnDias() {
            return nDias;
        }
    
        public void setnDias(String nDias) {
            this.nDias = nDias;
        }
    }
```

My application:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SistemacolaborativoApplication {
        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean getFilterJWT() {
            FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean();
            frb.setFilter(new TokenFilter());
            frb.addUrlPatterns("/#/*");
    
            return frb;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SistemacolaborativoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

My pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.3.jre17</version>
    <!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>6.20.6</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <!--            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <!--            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
                <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                <version>20.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.2.6.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

When I correct an error, the second one happens, and the same situation happens in several classes, I couldn't find any solution on the internet

Comment: Remove all the hibernate dependencies. starter-jpa is enough

Comment: it is impossible to read your codes because of long names , please in the examples you provided update your question and make class and method names  short/simple

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of your package structure, I am guessing spring boot component scan is not reaching your package.

Comment: Your code is not complete. The repository LogisticaGLGLDocumentosRepository references the class br.coopercarga.com.br.domain.Logistica.TblLogisticaGlgldocumentos which is not an entity known to hibernate causes the error.